# Is there any way i can make this two boxes slide in from each side when scroll down?

Tags: javascript, html, css

Im trying to make this two boxes slide in from each side like an animation when i scroll down the page. Could someone show me how, i have been trying to look it up on google but dont find it.

```css
.row{ 
display: inline-block;
margin-top: 60px;
}
.image-happy {
 height: 300px;
 width: 455px;
 float: left;
  background: url(/TeknikSnabben/assets/image/happy.jpg);
  border-radius: 50px 20px;
}
.text-happy {
 float: left;
 width: 450px;
 height: 300px;
 margin: 20px;
  font-size: 14px;
  font-weight: 300; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
}
.text-happy p{
  font-size: 18px;
  font-weight: 300; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.6;
}
.text-happy h3{
  font-size: 23px;
  font-weight: 400px; 
  font-family: 'Open Sans', sans-serif;
  opacity: 0.5;
}
```

```html
   <div class="row">
            <div class="image-happy"></div>
            <div class="text-happy"><h3>NÖJDA KUNDER<hr width="200px"></h3><p> möjligt sa ser vi till att ge det en chans.</p></div>
            </div>
```

[image]

Answer (score 1):

So, you wanted to move two elements in from opposite sides as the user scrolls down using html, css, and javascript. First we will need to set up the divs (or whatever element) in our html file:

**Index.html**

```
<html>
  <head>
    <link rel='stylesheet' href='style.css'>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class='txt_1' id='txt_1'>Left</div>
    <div class='txt_2' id='txt_2'>Right</div>
    <script src='script.js'></script>
  </body>
</html>
```

Next we will have to set up out CSS, we will be using CSS transitions so that we don't have to deal with messy javascript animations.

**Style.css**

```
.txt_1 {

  width: 500px; /* or whatever you want */
  height: 100px; /* or whatever you want */
  background-color: red; /* so you can see it */
  position: absolute; /* allows to set the position of the element */
  top: 5000px; /* this is most likely off your screen */
  left: -500px; /* the width of the element with a "-" sign before it :3 */
  transition: 0.5s; /* a generic way of css animation (I was too lazy to put webkit stuffs) */

}

.txt_2 {

  width: 500px; /* or whatever you want */
  height: 100px; /* or whatever you want */
  background-color: orange; /* so you can see it */
  position: absolute; /* allows to set the position of the element */
  top: 4000px /* because its not 5000px */
  right: 500px; /* the width of the element*/
  transition: 0.5s; /* a generic way of css animation (I was too lazy to put webkit stuffs) */

}
```

Next we will have to simply use some logic to change the elements position when the user scrolls.

**Script.js**

```
document.body.onscroll = function () {
  // scroll height + height of window > txt_1 Y position (parseInt(document.getElementById('txt_1').style.top, 10))
  if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > 5000) {

    // top of div is on screen, if you add or subtract numbers to the first part of the if statement, you will change the offset at wich is slides in
    // gives div new position of right on screen border (or float left)
    document.getElementById('txt_1').style.left = 0;

  }

  // scroll height + height of window > txt_2 Y position (document.getElementById('txt_2').style.top)
  if (window.scrollY + window.innerHeight > 4000) {

    // top of div is on screen, if you add or subtract numbers to the first part of the if statement, you will change the offset at wich is slides in
    // gives div new position of right on screen border (or float right)
    document.getElementById('txt_2').style.right = 0;

  }

}
```

That should answer your question (How do I get an element slide in on scroll?). The code should work, but I wrote it on the fly so... it have an error or two. *Any errors should be an easy fix e.g add a semicolon*

Answer (score 0):

Would you consider using a library? There's some great ones out there like http://scrollmagic.io/ that allow you to trigger events based on the scroll position.